# updatesystem does not consider config json

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to perform system update from command line with a json config but it seems that, no matter what I do,
the command does the exact same thing, which I suppose is running the update with the default platform settings.

For example, when I tried to perform my update without essential data("essential": "false" in json config), essential impexes are also being run.

I tried with an invalid json(that does not have json format) and the build was successfull.
I also tried giving as a paramter a json that does not exist and yet, the build was successfull and essential impexes were also run.

So, it seems to me that, **no matter what I do, the json is not taken into account and the update works with the default platform settings**.

This is the command I am using:

```
ant  updatesystem -Dtenant=master -DconfigFile=Path/updatesystem.json
```

Am I doing something wrong or how can I pass my configuration during system update from command line ?

PS:
Hybris version: **6.7.0.25**

Comment: In order to avoid running essential data , "update.importEssentialData.enabled=false" can be put in local.properties. This property is checked by UpdatePlatformAntPerformableImpl during system update

Answer (score 0):

I Think your JSON path is wrong and please try to do it like this.

ant updatesystem -DconfigFile=../custom/testcore/resources/updatesystem-configuration.json

Comment: sorry for my late answer. I also tried it like this: ant updatesystem -DconfigFile=updatesystem.json , and this config json was present in my platform folder. Still , it did not work...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fact that the "updatesystem" macro was overriden in a project specific file and the *configFile* property was not passed to the **UpdatePlatformAntPerformableImpl** during creation. That is why, regardless of my input for *configFile* property , nothing changed.

I fixed the problem by also passing the configFile in the constructor:

```
new de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.UpdatePlatformAntPerformableImpl("${tenant}", "${configFile}")
```